# Problem with ShowDialog when ShowInTaskbar is false

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is a small code that will illustrate my problem:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 3000;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        using (Form form = new Form())
        {
            form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            form.ShowDialog();
        }

    }
}
```

If I press `button1` (which calls `button1_Click`) and then click on another application in the taskbar so that it comes to the top, and then after 5 secs I go back to my application, the created form won't be visible and I won't have a way to bring it back to the top, while my `Form1` will be unresponsive because of having an invisible dialog on top.

What's a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your main form an owner of your modal box.

```
Form form = new Form();
form.Owner = this;
form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
form.ShowDialog();
```